# How can I scroll programmatically a div with its own scrollbars?

Tags: css, html

I have a HTML page with an internal DIV used for content. The internal DIV has its own scrollbars. I would like to automatically scroll to a certain position in the DIV.

How can I do this? (Note that I do NOT want to auto scroll the Window scrollbars - I already know how to do this)

A cross platform solution is needed

Answer (score 57, accepted):

The div has a `scrollTop` property that you can set (and its pal, `scrollLeft`).

- [jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/AgLyU/)
- [`scrollTop` on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.scrollTop)
- [`scrollLeft` on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.scrollLeft)

Answer (score 5):

there is this `.scrollTo()` method which can help you scroll through your divs. try it for more info visit [here](http://www.roseindia.net/javascript/javascript-scrollto-method.shtml)

Answer (score 3):

As long as JavaScript is acceptable, I created a [demo using jQuery](http://jsfiddle.net/cchana/MjPBk/) that uses a known element with an ID inside the `div`.

```
$(function() {
    var testOffset = $('#test').offset(),
        scrollOffset = $('#scroll').offset();
    $('#scroll').scrollTop(testOffset.top - scrollOffset.top);
});​
```

If you only know how far, in terms of pixels, rather than to a specific element, it could be adapted to:

```
$(function() {
    $('#scroll').scrollTop(100);
});​
```

Answer (score 2):

Add a div (where you want to scroll):

```
<div id="#scroll-here">Test..</div>
```

and add a link like this:

```
<a href="#scroll-here">Scroll to Test</a>
```

if you want a smooth scroll you can check [this](http://www.sycha.com/jquery-smooth-scrolling-internal-anchor-links)

Comment: He didn't mean to scroll the "page" to that specific element. He intended to scroll to a particular position "inside" that "overflowed div" itself.

Answer (score 1):

You have to target taht div and set scrollLeft. scrollTop property.

```
const scrollingDivElement = document.getElementsByClassName("class_name");
if(scrollingDivElement && scrollingDivElement.length > 0){
      //this is the div element that scrolls
      scrollingDivElement[0].scrollLeft += 50;
}
```

Comment: I think this is already the solution proposed in the accepted answer

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend having a look at the [scrollTo jQuery plugin](http://flesler.blogspot.co.uk/2007/10/jqueryscrollto.html). It's a really handy plugin that allows you to animate a scroll within any element. I've setup a small example in [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FDbAX/1/) that demonstrates how it works. The example shows how you "scroll to" the third `p` in the first `div`, and then the second `p` in the second `div`. One thing worth noting, is that to ensure the `position().top` is correct, you'll need to set the containing `div` to have a `position: relative;`. Hopefully this isn't too much of a problem though. :)