# I have an unordered list and i want to scroll to clickable element

Tags: javascript, css

This list is horizontal in the mobile view - using display:inline-block and its scrollable.

```
<ul>
  <li>Home<li>
  <li>Accounts<li>
  <li>Contact US<li>
  <li>About us</li>
  <li>Last button</li>
</ul>
```

You can't see the last button because you need to scroll to it, what I want to happen is when you click on " About US " it scrolls to its location and then you will see " Last Button "
Basically scroll in the X axis to the element clicked.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14023765/so-dom-scrollintoview-aligns-top-bottom-but-what-about-left-right#14024470

Answer (score 2):

You can use an anchor to "focus" the div. I.e:

```
<ul id="ulList">
  <li>Home<li>
  <li>Accounts<li>
  <li>Contact US<li>
  <li id="about">About us</li>
  <li>Last button</li>
</ul>
```

and then use the following javascript:

```
location.href = "#";
location.href = "#about";
```

You can use a library if needed Check [jQuery.ScrollTo](https://github.com/flesler/jquery.scrollTo),

Edited :

```
var about= document.getElementById('about');
var top = about.offsetTop;

// Now we tell the div to scroll to that position using scrollTop:
document.getElementById('ulList').scrollTop = top;
```

Comment: Problem is the whole screen goes down to it.

Comment: If the answer worked for you, you can click on the checked icon left of the answer 

Answer (score 0):

Try using [bootstrap scrolling Nav module](https://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/scrolling-nav/):

JavaScript

```
<script>
    $(".navbar-nav li a").click(function(event) {
        if (!$(this).parent().hasClass('dropdown'))
            $(".navbar-collapse").collapse('hide');
    });   </script>


<ul id="ulList" class="navbar-nav ml-auto" style="z-index:1;">
  <li>Home<li>
  <li>Accounts<li>
  <li>Contact US<li>
  <li id="about">About us</li>
  <li>Last button</li>
</ul>

<div class="about" id="ulList">
    <div class="container">
      test
    </div>
  </div>
```