# How to scroll for two divs with only the scroll of the container div

Tags: javascript, html, css

The first `div`'s content is longer, than the second `div` and I want to use one scrollbar (container `div`) for both.

When scrolling down for the two `div`s, I need the second `div` to scroll until it reaches the end of its content, then stop scrolling and the first `div` continue scrolling until it reaches the end of its content.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="first"></div>
  <div class="second"></div>
</div>
<style>
  .container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-between;
    overflow: auto;
    height: calc(100vh - 40rem);
  }

  .first {
    width: 50%;
  }

  .second {
    width: 50%;
  }
</style>
```

Comment: besides the fact that the question description is very unclear. The code does not provide something to help us understand. So, please share code, in a working code snippet ( `<>` icon in the edit question toolbar ) that shows us what you have tried . Plus, please take the time to format your question so we can understand what exactly are you trying to achieve.

Comment: consider a container with two divs aside, i want to scroll both with only one scroll, the first div is shorter than the other, so i want to both till their end separately.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution could be using the code from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10634898/how-can-i-scroll-programmatically-a-div-with-its-own-scrollbars)

```
var element= document.getElementById('firstelement');
element.scrollTop = countedPixel;
```

You can count the pixel scrolled like [this](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_scroll.asp) or with the native js function Example [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onscroll.asp)

```
<div onscroll="doSomething()">
```