# scrolling should be done within a div when an event is ocured not on the entire body

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a `div` with an id of `test` like below:

```
<div id="test"></div>
```

this `div` is scrollable as I set `overflow-y` to `scroll`

When I click on a button this `div` should be scrolled to another `div` position. So what I did is I used Javascript `scrollTo` method and scrolled to some random position Like this :

```
document.getElementById('test').scrollTo(0,300)
```

As I mentioned my `id` reference here and with the scroll method, I thought only the `div` will be scrolled but the entire website is getting scrolled.

How should I scroll the `div` to a certain position when a button is clicked and it should only scroll inside the `div` not the body's `div`.

I want this to be done in pure JavaScript, No jQuery should be used in my project.

Comment: have you already seen https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10634898/how-can-i-scroll-programmatically-a-div-with-its-own-scrollbars ?

Comment: You need to assign height to test id
#test {height: 400px;overflow-y:auto;}

Answer (score 0):

Its working fine?

```js
var div = document.getElementById("test");
div.scrollTo(0,100)
```

```css
#test{
height:200px;
overflow:scroll;
}
body{
height:1000px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test">
<p>test</p>
<p>test</p>
<p>test</p>
<p>test</p>
<p>test</p>
<p>test</p>
<p>test</p>
<p>test</p>
<p>test</p>
<p>test</p>
<p>test</p>
<p>test</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `scrollTop` property for scolling specific elements within the page. See this documentation for details:

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_element_scrolltop.asp

So your code would be changed to this for scrolling to position `300`:

```
document.getElementById('test').scrollTop = 300
```